# Change background color of textview on touch

Tags: android, ontouchlistener

I'm having to simulate a list view because I have a very lengthy layout, where I'm using a scrollview. To simulate a list view, I'm using a linear layout having a vertical orientation containing the following layout a number of times

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_text_view_directclass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I'm wishing to simulate the ontouch event on each of these item to change the background color of each of these item when the user touches it. Also, I need to have click event for each of the item

The code below does not work very fine.

```
final View rowView = getActivity().getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.text_view_directclass, null);

                 rowView.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {

                    @Override
                    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                        switch(event.getAction()) {
                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
                                break;
                           case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                                v.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
                                break;
                       }
                       return true;
                    }
                });
```

It correctly toggles the color on action up and action down. But I select a "row" then moves my finger down without leaving the screen and then leave the screen, it doesn't change the color of that row. ANy better solution?

I've tried using a selector based on the first answer. It doesn't work,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/directsubclass_row_selector"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/txt_text_view_directclass"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:padding="10dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
        <View
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="1dp"
                android:background="@android:color/darker_gray"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

**Selector code:**

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/abs__background_holo_light"/>
    <item android:drawable="@color/abs__background_holo_dark"/>
</selector>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my solution as I've used it in one of my projects:

```
view.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        switch(event.getAction())
        {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.pressed);
                lastY = event.getY();

                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                float abs = Math.abs(lastY - event.getY());

                if(abs > 5)
                    v.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.normal);

                break;
        }

        return true;
    }
});
```

Not the cleanest solution ever but it's working... 
You can change the motion threshold (5) to fit your application's requirements.

Answer (score 0):

set a selector as background, something like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

<item android:state_focused="true" android:drawable="@color/red"/>
<item android:drawable="@color/white"/>

</selector>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer, but it doesn't work, i've updated my question with your suggestion